# AS3 Event.ENTER_FRAME tips for game developer

Tags: flash, actionscript

Im new to flash game developing and currently i am developing my first game. RPG Action Game. I`m having a problem with ENTER_FRAME Event.

I currently have 3 ENTER_FRAME Events, from my document class, hero and ground. Each time I run the application, the flash player crashes.

What would be a good approach with this problem? I am thinking to have one main enterframe event which controls everything and change my design pattern.. T_T.

Comment: I don't think that having 3 ENTER_FRAME listeners would cause application crash. Look elsewhere.

Comment: What kind of crash is it? Do you get an error message? What kind of code is in your enterFrames? Try to remove some code until it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your document class you could have:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
private function onEnter(e:Event):void
{
    hero.update();
    ground.update();
    //do other stuff    
}
```

Comment: Yes Green Pineapple, im trying to achieve that kind of approach. Im new to any procedural approach so studying one or 2 design patterns is a way to go..i guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the best approach is to use one main `enterframe` to maintain the speed. You can use many `enterframes`, but I expect that it will decrease the speed.